# Firebase/Angular2 - load database table once

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to call my database table once, and I thought it would be simple but I'm constantly getting an error!

> TypeError: this.database.object(...).take is not a function

This is my `.ts` file:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  userData:any;
  locationRef:FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private storage: Storage,
    private database: AngularFireDatabase) {

      this.locationRef = this.database.object('location' , { preserveSnapshot: true }).take(1)
      console.log(this.locationRef)

  }
```

I thought this would work but it's not... What am I doing wrong?

My firebase table looks like:

```
|firebase-name
   - location
      - location-item-1
      - location-item-2
      etc..
```

I want to get the snapshot of the table once and loop through it..

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was I had to do `this.database.database` which is slightly confusing...